# Execute query by looping through values within a subquery

Tags: sql, vba, oracle, adodb

I'm at loss of what I'm trying to achieve is even possible, so I'm reaching out to the experts here to provide some guidance.

I have created an excel macro which runs several queries across multiple Oracle DBs. One problem I have is that one of the queries can only use a single value in the where clause during execution as I need to retrieve only the first row of data (where rownum=1) and there can be several hundred of these unique values.

The only way I have been able to execute this is to create a range of values in excel, open the DB connection, execute the query, write the results back to the spreadsheet, close the connection and then move onto the next value in the range, repeating this for every value in the range. This has proven to be extremely inefficient so I'm looking for a way to loop through the values directly in the DB.

The entire query is over 650 lines, but I've provided a snippet to help provide some clarity on what I'm looking to achieve.
"START" is the beginning of the subquery which pulls the unique values (GS_GRP_SEQ) that I need to loop through and "END" is the end of the subquery.

I sincerely appreciate your time in assisting me with this!

```
    SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT TRIM(CS.CS_NBR) AS CS_Num, TRIM(CS.CS_NAM) AS CName, 
    TO_CHAR(to_date(CS.CS_EFF_DAT,'yyyymmdd'),'mm/dd/yyyy') AS C_Eff_Dte,
    CASE CS.UR_ID
    WHEN 'ABC' THEN 'JOHNNY PARKER'
    WHEN '999' THEN 'UNDEFINED'
    END AS UR_Name,
    G.GS_GRP_SEQ as GR_Num, 
    Case G.GS_STAT
    WHEN '0' THEN 'READY'
    END AS GR_Stat,
    CASE G.GS_FUN_ARR
    WHEN '1' THEN 'INCREASED'
    WHEN '9' THEN 'DECREASED'
    END AS Type_Desc,
    R.RT_TOT_RATE AS RATE_TOT,
    TO_CHAR(to_date(R.RT_TOT_RATE_EFF_DT,'yyyymmdd'),'mm/dd/yyyy') as RT_Eff_Dte, 
    R.RT_TOT_1 as Rate_Type_1, R.RT_AMT_1 as Rate_Amount_1, 
    R.RT_TOT_2 as Rate_Type_2, R.RT_AMT_2 as Rate_Amount_2
    FROM MNDB.CASE CS 
    inner join MNDB.CADR CA on CA.CS_ROOT_KEY = CS.CS_NBR
    inner join MNDB.GRPR G on CS.CS_NBR = G.GS_CS_NBR
    inner join MNDB.GCNT GC on GC.GS_GRP_SEQ = G.GS_GRP_SEQ
    inner join MNDB.TOTR R on R.ACCESS_LEVEL = GC.GS_GRP_SEQ
    INNER JOIN MNDB.PROD P ON TRIM(P.PROD_GRP) = TRIM(G.GS_PROD_CD) 
    LEFT JOIN MNDB.GNAT NAT ON G.GS_GRP_SEQ = NAT.GS_GRP_SEQ
    WHERE CS.CS_NBR = ('123456') 
    AND G.GS_GRP_SEQ IN 
--START--    
   (SELECT DISTINCT GS_GRP_SEQ FROM MNDP.GRPR where CS.CS_NBR = ('123456') and GS_STAT_CD in ('0','2','6') 
--END--
   ORDER BY CA.CS_ADR_PRC_DTE desc, RT_TOT_RATE_EFF_DT desc, RT_TOT_RATE_TERM_DT ASC ) where rownum=1
```

Comment: write all the IN clauses values from the spreadsheet to a temp table, then included that in your query

Comment: I don't believe that solution would work here as I cannot use IN since I need to pull the first row of data (where rownum=1) for the given GS_GRP_SEQ value.

Comment: So just include GS_GRP_SEQ in the ORDER BY

Comment: What is your Oracle version?

Comment: @NickW - I tried that but only one row came back when I was expecting four rows. Again, I believe this is due to 'where rownum = 1'.

Comment: @astentx - Oracle version is 3.2.20.10.21

Comment: 3.2.20... is something different. Please, execute `select * from v$version` and check the output. `rownum` is of course the reason, but you may use `row_number` for this task or in modern releases there are also possibilities to do `fetch first` with lateral join

Comment: @astentx - ORA-00942: table or view does not exist. Any other way to obtain this information?

Comment: @Brian try this as a test: `select * from dual fetch first row only;` If that runs without error, then you are on 12.1 or later and you might be able to simplify the fetch-the-first-row logic somewhat.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson that ran without error. The result came back with column "DUMMY" and value "X".

Comment: I was able to get it resolved by using @NickW's solution below. Thank you all for your time and willingness to help!

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. You cannot edit your question to add the solution - that's a violation of the site's guidelines. If you found a solution that you want to share, do so by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information. You should edit to break up that wall of text at the top into readable paragraphs - it's pretty difficult to read now.

Comment: @KenWhite I've followed your guidance and made the suggested edits. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your inner SQL statement, add a new column like this:

```
row_number () over (
           partition by <list of columns in each group>
           order by <required columns> desc
         ) rn
```

Then in the outer SQL filter:

```
where rn=1
```

Comment: Brilliant! This did it. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

Using the solution provided by @NickW I was able to achieve the desired results by modifying the code as follows:

```
    SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT TRIM(CS.CS_NBR) AS CS_Num, TRIM(CS.CS_NAM) AS CName, 
    TO_CHAR(to_date(CS.CS_EFF_DAT,'yyyymmdd'),'mm/dd/yyyy') AS C_Eff_Dte,
    CASE CS.UR_ID
    WHEN 'ABC' THEN 'JOHNNY PARKER'
    WHEN '999' THEN 'UNDEFINED'
    END AS UR_Name,
    G.GS_GRP_SEQ as GR_Num, 
    Case G.GS_STAT
    WHEN '0' THEN 'READY'
    END AS GR_Stat,
    CASE G.GS_FUN_ARR
    WHEN '1' THEN 'INCREASED'
    WHEN '9' THEN 'DECREASED'
    END AS Type_Desc,
    R.RT_TOT_RATE AS RATE_TOT,
    TO_CHAR(to_date(R.RT_TOT_RATE_EFF_DT,'yyyymmdd'),'mm/dd/yyyy') as RT_Eff_Dte, 
    R.RT_TOT_1 as Rate_Type_1, R.RT_AMT_1 as Rate_Amount_1, 
    R.RT_TOT_2 as Rate_Type_2, R.RT_AMT_2 as Rate_Amount_2,
row_number () over (
           PARTITION BY GS_GRP_SEQ
           ORDER BY GS_GRP_SEQ, CA.CS_ADR_PRC_DTE desc, RT_TOT_RATE_EFF_DT desc, RT_TOT_RATE_TERM_DT ASC
         ) rn
    FROM MNDB.CASE CS 
    inner join MNDB.CADR CA on CA.CS_ROOT_KEY = CS.CS_NBR
    inner join MNDB.GRPR G on CS.CS_NBR = G.GS_CS_NBR
    inner join MNDB.GCNT GC on GC.GS_GRP_SEQ = G.GS_GRP_SEQ
    inner join MNDB.TOTR R on R.ACCESS_LEVEL = GC.GS_GRP_SEQ
    INNER JOIN MNDB.PROD P ON TRIM(P.PROD_GRP) = TRIM(G.GS_PROD_CD) 
    LEFT JOIN MNDB.GNAT NAT ON G.GS_GRP_SEQ = NAT.GS_GRP_SEQ
    WHERE CS.CS_NBR = ('123456') 
    AND G.GS_GRP_SEQ IN    
   (SELECT DISTINCT GS_GRP_SEQ FROM MNDP.GRPR where CS.CS_NBR = ('123456') and GS_STAT_CD in ('0','2','6') 
   ORDER BY GS_GRP_SEQ 
) where rn=1
```